# HTML Which control was selected from several identical controls?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a list of Soccer players, who I'm displaying in a simple HTML table. Alongside each player, I want a drop-down box to allow the player to be selected/dropped/subbed from the team. When the drop-down box is changed, two things need to happen, firstly I need to update the player info in the database (I know how to do that in PHP) and secondly I want to refresh the list (though I can deal with that later).

My question is, how do I work out which of the many drop-down boxes has been altered? I'm populating the table by looping through the players. Each has his own hidden ID code, so in other languages, I would somehow add this ID code to the drop-down box next to his name, then when responding, I could pull this value out and use that for the update. Is there some way that I can do that using HTML/Javascript/PHP? Or some other method for associating each control with the player on each row?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP and JS, just name the dropdown using the hidden ID you talked about when writing the HTML. Then you can use JS to determine which dropdown is being changed.

HTML for dropdown something like:

```
<select name="player_id" onchange="updatePlayer()">
 <option value="selected">Selected</option>
 <option value="dropped">Dropped</option>
 <option value="subbed">Subbed</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function updatePlayer() {
    // Do update
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda what I thought, but one problem. The ID is stored in a PHP object, so I'm not sure how to add that to the 'name' attribute, other than doing name=<?php echo $Player->ID; ?> onchange.. etc'. The problem is, the code requires something after the php section, such as a period or some other character. So I end up with something like 1. 2. 3. etc. I guess the dot could be removed in the function, but is there another way to do this?

Comment: Actually it seems to work fine without the trailing character, but Netbeans is giving an error. Ignoring the error seems to work and when I check the page source, I do now just have the ID as the 'name'. But would prefer not to have the errors in Netbeans.

Comment: Can't you do something like this?
name="<?php echo $Player->ID . ""; ?>"